# Cannot reinstall macos with internet recovery

Tags: macos

Bought an old macbook off ebay no harddrive, installed one now cannot renstall lion, item not available.

Comment: Which macbook exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy Lion [& Mountain Lion] - they're the last ones you actually had to pay for, all since then have been free.

https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion  or
https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/D6377ZM/A/os-x-mountain-lion

The links don't have a universal translator to your own country's Apple Store, unlike most Apple links, so you may have to search your local store instead.

*From comments*
It seems you can manually edit your own country code into the above links to find your correct Store. Apple links are normally smarter than that - but at least it *can* be done.

Comment: Actually you can just edit the URL with your country code. i.e. https://www.apple.com/fr/shop/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion

Comment: Ah… so you can. You can usually just knock out the country code & each territory will find its own page. This one's "smart but not *that* smart" so it seems you can edit it in yourself.